# How did Dante die?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-2003

In FMA Wikia, it says Dante is deceased, but how did she die?

In one of the episodes of the FMA 2003 Anime, we see Dante escaping in an elevator, but is confronted by Gluttony. All we see is her saying "Not now Gluttony, I'll feed you later", and then we see Gluttony lunging at her and her clapping her hands, but that's it.

I'm assuming she died from being eaten, but it sounds unlikely that after 400 years she would be beaten by someone as stupid as Gluttony. So how did she die? Not so sure on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not exactly clear, as Dante is about to use Alchemy on Gluttony in the elevator.

In the movie *Conqueror of Shamballa*, Al and Wrath encounter a monster with the Uroboros Tatoo in the underground city and Wrath says that it's Gluttony. We can only assume that Gluttony devoured Dante just after she managed to do something to Gluttony causing him to mutate.

As for your final comment, she had little time left as she was complaining how the stone she had was about ran out. This means that not only would she not be able to jump bodies anymore, but her rotting soul was also destroying new bodies much more quickly. Even if she wasn't eaten by Gluttony, with no Homunculi to serve her, the stone almost out of power and unable to manipulate the State to create new Homunculi for her, Dante's existence would have ended not long after. That's my speculation, though.

Answer (score 0):

Dante was powerful, and everytime we actually saw Gluttony eat someone, there was blood everywhere. Since the elevator was clean, it can be assumed Dante escaped and moved to a new body and started the quest for a new stone soon after.